# how do I make my oledb program work on a different pc

Tags: c#, database, oledb

Hey I'm new to programming and have never made an actual program that needs to work on another pc. The program is connected with a databank. When I'm on another pc i change program.exe.config file so that i can apply the right location of the databank but its still doesn't work. here is the code i have, maybe something is wrong here. 
app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Program.Properties.Settings.InventoryDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\School\Stage\Program testen\Program\bin\Debug\InventoryDB.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

in standard code:

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\School\Stage\Program testen\Program\bin\Debug\InventoryDB.accdb");
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have this path `D:\School\Stage\Program testen\Program\bin\Debug` in that PC?

Comment: it works on my pc, but when i transfer it to a different one, I open program.exe.config so i can change the location on THAT pc and when I run it shows an error

Comment: What error is shown exactlly? Is Microsoft Access of the Microsoft Access Runtime installed on the target machine (given that you seem to use an Access Database as the backend)?

Comment: okay so in the other pc i changed the path in the program.exe.config, but it sais the path is invalid and then it shows the path of the previous pc location instead of the new one

Comment: well first off..don't assume that all  computers have the same `FilePath\Directory Names` as you do on your machine. I would add code to check if the directory exist on the users machine if not then Create the Directory, also this can be a potential issue as well because for example in `United States` for example `D:` drive is a CD/DVD Drive from what I have seen all PC's have at least a `C;` drive.. sounds like you may want to rethink your solution / support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that you are specifying a connection string in your application configuration file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Program.Properties.Settings.InventoryDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\School\Stage\Program testen\Program\bin\Debug\InventoryDB.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You aren't using the connection string from your **Program.exe.config**, instead you are copying-and-pasting the connection string.

If you change your code slightly, perhaps you can see what i mean:

```
//Get the connection string to use
String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\School\Stage\Program testen\Program\bin\Debug\InventoryDB.accdb";

//Open a connection to the database
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

What you should be doing is pulling the connection string from your application's configuration:

```
//Get our connection string setting, and the connectionString it contains
ConnectionStringSettings cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Program.Properties.Settings.InventoryDBConnectionString"];
String connectionString = cs.ConnectionString;

//Open a connection to the database
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

There is one more change that you can make. Your connection string entry itself specifies which provider you want to use:

```
providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
```

But then you go ahead and use that provider yourself:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(...);
```

If you changed your connection string to use a different provider:

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

your code would still be using the **OleDbConnection**, rather than the provider given in the application configuration.

Fortunately, the .NET framework has a handy little helper function, where it can create the correct provider **for** you:

```
public static DbConnection GetConnection()
{
    //Get the connection string info from our application config
    ConnectionStringSettings cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Program.Properties.Settings.InventoryDBConnectionString"];

    if (cs == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not find connection string settings");

    //Get the factory for the given provider (e.g. "System.Data.OleDbClient")
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(cs.ProviderName);

    if (factory == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not obtain factory for provider \"" + cs.ProviderName + "\"");

    //Have the factory give us the right connection object
    DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();

    if (conn == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not obtain connection from factory");

    //Knowing the connection string, open the connection
    conn.ConnectionString = cs.ConnectionString;
    conn.Open();

    return conn;
}
```